# How to use if else condition in sccs on float property?

Tags: if-statement, sass

I would to apply margin on image that use float property like this:

`<img style="float:left;" ...>`

as HTML, and this is the scss:

```
    $flottant: left;
     @if $flottant == left {
     img {
     // Cas de l'image en float left
     margin: 0 em(10px) 0 0;
     }
     } @else {
     margin: 0;
     }
```

But I don't know how to target the float propertie of the image...
If someone know about it.

Thanks

I try to evaluate the float property for image.

EDIT: I don't know how to include this code into a if/else condition, but I think it's a starting point to make difference between images with float and no float.

```
 img[style*="float: left"] {
 // Cas de l'image en float left
margin: 0 em(10px) 0 0;
}
         img{margin: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I clearly understand the question, but here is how I would trigger `float` property to apply the margin :

```
img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

img[style*="float: right"] {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I think the second way is the right one because flat is applied "by hand" via the text editor. So if I check the value for style I think I will can change margin depending on floating. I'll feedback

Comment: Let us know if this works for you

Comment: it works as is. Not sure about the need to include it in a if/else condition.

Comment: With the second option you don't need an if/else statement